# Use another layer model in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a novice in asp .net Core 3.1 programming. Thank you for your help.
I created three layers for my project, one for the core, one for the database and one for the web.

The models are in the ِDTOs folder. Now my problem is to create database tables. I do not have access to the Category model.
How can I solve this problem? I would be grateful if you could guide me in full detail.
The project error image as well as the dependencies on each layer are present in the image.

Due to the problem of uploading photos on the site, I had to upload them to another site

Images link
https://pasteboard.co/JNeXGKJ.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/JNeXsXs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your Category class is in the project `Pipeland.Core`.
Your project `Pipeland.Web` references `Pipeland.Core` but your project `Pipeland.DataLayer` does not.

At the moment, classes in `Pipeland.DataLayer` (including `PipelandContext`) can't access any classes in `Pipeland.Core` (including `Category`)

Create a project reference to `Pipeland.Core` in your `Pipeland.DataLayer` project.

Then add the line:

```
using Pipeland.Core.Dtos
```

to the top of your PipelandContext.cs file.

This assumes that your `Category` class is in the namespace `Pipeland.Core.Dtos`, which it might not be, but I expect it is.